# Group by timestamp a single CSV file - Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a almost endless horizontal csv where the variables are spreaded across the header and i have many repeated timestamps which results in a scenario like this:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Timestamp  |  Variable1 |  Variable2 |    ....    |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 2017/02/12 |     20     |            |            |  
| 2017/02/13 |     20     |            |            |   
| 2017/02/14 |     30     |            |            |
| 2017/02/12 |            |     5      |            |
| 2017/02/13 |            |     2      |            |
| 2017/02/14 |            |     10     |            |
|    ...     |            |            |            |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to concatenate by the timestamp in order to get a result like this:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Timestamp  |  Variable1 |  Variable2 |    ....    |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 2017/02/12 |     20     |     5      |            |   
| 2017/02/13 |     20     |     2      |            |   
| 2017/02/14 |     30     |     10     |            |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Im relatively new in pandas but i feel this can be done with ease with multiple dataframes but im having a little doubt grouping a single dataframe. Can anyone give me a hand? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can groupby timestamp and combine the values

```
df.groupby('Timestamp')['Variable1', 'Variable2'].apply(lambda x: x.sum()).reset_index()
```

You get

```
    Timestamp   Variable1   Variable2
0   2017/02/12  20          5
1   2017/02/13  20          2
2   2017/02/14  30          10
```

EDIT: More generic thanks to @piRSquared

```
df.set_index('Timestamp').groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index‌​()
```

Comment: The variables are too many. Can i apply same sort of df.columns[1:-1] in the brackets? :)

Comment: `df.set_index('Timestamp').groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index()`

Comment: Sorry guys, this is not working for me. Also, 
`df.set_index('Timestamp').groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index‌​()` throws me a sintaxe error.

Comment: I have used other sugestions and when i don't get errors i get only null values throughout the dataframe. For instance: 
`pd.concat([s.dropna() for c, s in df.set_index('Z Ts Read').iteritems()], axis=1)`here i get a "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" :/

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `pd.concat` + `pd.DataFrame.iteritems`

```
pd.concat([s.dropna() for c, s in df.set_index('Timestamp').iteritems()], axis=1)

            Variable1  Variable2
Timestamp                       
2017/02/12       20.0        5.0
2017/02/13       20.0        2.0
2017/02/14       30.0       10.0
```

---

*with `reset_index`*

```
pd.concat(
    [s.dropna() for c, s in df.set_index('Timestamp').iteritems()],
    axis=1
).reset_index()

    Timestamp  Variable1  Variable2
0  2017/02/12       20.0        5.0
1  2017/02/13       20.0        2.0
2  2017/02/14       30.0       10.0
```

Comment: Hi and thank you, i tried your solution and i got a ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. Any idea?

Comment: That's because you have duplicate dates for the values that are present in the columns.  That could be because you have blank strings `''` and not nulls `None` or `NaN`.  **If** that is the case, you could try this `df.replace({'': None}, ).set_index('Timestamp').iteritems()` in place of `df.set_index('Timestamp').iteritems()`

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest solutions:

[`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) with parameter `level=0`:

```
df = df.set_index('Timestamp').sum(level=0)
print (df)
            Variable1  Variable2
Timestamp                       
2017/02/12       20.0        5.0
2017/02/13       20.0        2.0
2017/02/14       30.0       10.0

df = df.set_index('Timestamp').sum(level=0).reset_index()
print (df)
    Timestamp  Variable1  Variable2
0  2017/02/12       20.0        5.0
1  2017/02/13       20.0        2.0
2  2017/02/14       30.0       10.0
```

[`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Timestamp').sum()
print (df)
            Variable1  Variable2
Timestamp                       
2017/02/12       20.0        5.0
2017/02/13       20.0        2.0
2017/02/14       30.0       10.0
```

---

```
df = df.groupby('Timestamp').sum().reset_index()
print (df)
    Timestamp  Variable1  Variable2
0  2017/02/12       20.0        5.0
1  2017/02/13       20.0        2.0
2  2017/02/14       30.0       10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.groupby()` chained with `.sum()`

`df_grouped = df.groupby('Timestamp').sum()`

This aggregates the data by group (in this case, Timestamp) by summing each column for that group. In your example, each column has one entry per date so summing should provide the correct solution.